# JAVA -AWS ACCESS S3 BUCKET FROM JAVA APPLICATION ON ELASTIC BEANSTALK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to upload files from my Java Spring application to S3 bucket.

After configure credentials in ./aws/credentials this work for me on localhost.

But, I tried on Elastic Beanstalk but not working. I receive the message "Permission denied".

I configure the aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role to grant access to AmazonS3FullAccess, and configure enviroment properties from Sowtware configuration on Elastic Beanstalk application.

My code to initialize AmazonClient:

`this.s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
                .build();`

aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role Configuration:

[View here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8PnB.png)

Am I skipping something?

Comment: Don't you have to specify credential provider for java sdk? For example, config file, role, env variables? Maybe you use incorrect provider?

Comment: @Marcin I specified "and configure enviroment properties from Sowtware configuration on Elastic Beanstalk application.". Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Not very familiar with Java sdk, but remember ppl having issues with using wrong provider. Don't know if its applies here, just something to consider for you.

Answer (score 0):

Did You check security group on ec2? Because as You probably know ElasticBeanstalk create EC2 instance as well. Maybe You block outbound traffic?

Comment: Outbound rules is setted on All traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not setting the environment variables on Elastic Beanstalk and setting the Service Clients properly. Read this AWS Tutorial. It shows you how to interact with Amazon S3 from a Spring Boot application.

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/scmacdon/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)